# JavaScript to check which CSS classes are NOT in use on a page

Tags: javascript

I am building a JavaScript snippet that I am using to check which CSS classes are NOT in use on a page. Here is the code:

```
function httpGet(theUrl) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
  xmlHttp.send( null );
  return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

function getAllClasses() {
  //get inline css classes
  let headContent = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
  let classes = getAllCSSClasses(headContent);
  //get external linraties
  let csses = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]'); 
  for (i = 0; i < csses.length; ++i) {
    if (csses[i].href && csses[i].href.indexOf("cookieconsent") == -1){
      let styledata = httpGet(csses[i].href);
      let cclasses = getAllCSSClasses(styledata);
      if ( cclasses instanceof Array )
         classes = classes.concat( cclasses );
      else
         classes.push( cclasses );      
      //console.log(csses[i].href)
      //classes = Object.assign([], classes, cclasses);
      //console.log(classes)
      //classes.concat(cclasses);

    }
  }
  return classes;
}

function getAllCSSClasses(cssdata) {
  var re = /\.[a-zA-Z_][\w-_]*[^\.\s\{#:\,;]/g;
  var m;
  let classes = [];
  do {
    m = re.exec(cssdata);
    if (m) {
      for(let key in m) {
        if(
           (typeof m[key] == "string") && 
           (classes.indexOf(m[key]) == -1) &&
           (m[key].indexOf(".") == 0)
          )
          classes.push(m[key].replace(/\s/g, " "));
      }
    }
  } while (m);
  return classes;
}

function getHTMLUsedClasses() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var unique = function (list, x) {
    if (x != "" && list.indexOf(x) === -1) {
        list.push(x);
    }
    return list;
  };
  var htmlclasses = [].reduce.call(elements, function (acc, e) {
    if (typeof e.className == "string"){
      return [].slice.call(e.classList).reduce(unique, acc);    
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }, []);
  return htmlclasses;
}


function getUndefinedClasses(cssclasses, htmlclasses) {
  var undefinedclasses = [];
  for (let key in htmlclasses) {
    if(cssclasses.indexOf("." + htmlclasses[key])  == -1 ) {
       undefinedclasses.push(htmlclasses[key]);
    }
  }
  return undefinedclasses;
}

var cssclasses = getAllClasses();

var htmlclasses = getHTMLUsedClasses();

var un = getUndefinedClasses(cssclasses, htmlclasses);

console.log(un )
//copy(un);
```

Now, the problem is in getHTMLUsedClasses, it doesn't work well.

For example, HTML has an 'img-responsive' class, but the output doesn't show it

```
  var unique = function (list, x) {
    if (x != "" && list.indexOf(x) === -1) {
        //img-responsive here exists
        list.push(x);
    }
    return list;
  };
```

but:

```
  var htmlclasses = [].reduce.call(elements, function (acc, e) {
    if (typeof e.className == "string"){
      return [].slice.call(e.classList).reduce(unique, acc);   
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }, []);
  //doesn't exists in the final htmlclasses
  return htmlclasses;
```

So I am guessing that [].slice.call(e.classList).reduce(unique, acc) is not working well. I don't quite understand what 'reduce' is doing here (I took this from another example). Can anyone explain?

Comment: I wouldn't be using `.className` at all. I'd be using the `.classList` API, which is much easier.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks, Ive changed "return  e.className.split(' ').map(trim).reduce(unique, acc);" to "return  [].slice.call(e.classList).reduce(unique, acc);" still nothing changed in the result output

Comment: I'm the author of [email-comb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-comb) which does remove unused CSS, and without using a parser. The [final ESM build](https://github.com/codsen/codsen/blob/main/packages/email-comb/dist/email-comb.esm.js) is 1184 lines long, it's got 378 asserts in unit tests. Unused CSS search is not a trivial task! If I may advise anything, use TDD, write unit tests first, go little by little. Wire up "dev" and "prod" builds in Rollup and keep `console.log` in the source, strip them in "prod" build. That way you can inspect what's going on in the terminal.

Comment: FYI: `.classList` returns an array, so `[].slice.call()` is not needed. You can go straight to `e.classList.reduce()`.

Comment: But classList also has some functions, so I wanted to make sure that only the array is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found what was the issue. I read that "reduce() does not execute the function for array elements without values." and some classes can come empty so "return [];" will destroy all that is in the array so far. And instead I think that I have to return accumulator like this:

```
function getHTMLUsedClasses() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var unique = function (list, x) {
    if (x && list.indexOf(x) === -1) {
        list.push(x);
    }
    return list;
  };
  var htmlclasses = [].reduce.call(elements, function (acc, e) {
    if (e.classList.length > 0){
      return  [].slice.call(e.classList).reduce(unique, acc);      
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
  }, []);
  return htmlclasses;
}
```

Now the resulting array looks much better, I have in it "img-responsive".

Here is the whole code again:

```
function httpGet(theUrl) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
  xmlHttp.send( null );
  return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

function getAllClasses() {
  //get inline css classes
  let headContent = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
  let classes = getAllCSSClasses(headContent);
  //get external linraties
  let csses = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]'); 
  for (i = 0; i < csses.length; ++i) {
    if (csses[i].href && csses[i].href.indexOf("cookieconsent") == -1){
      let styledata = httpGet(csses[i].href);
      let cclasses = getAllCSSClasses(styledata);
      if ( cclasses instanceof Array )
         classes = classes.concat( cclasses );
      else
         classes.push( cclasses );      

    }
  }
  return classes;
}

function getAllCSSClasses(cssdata) {
  var re = /\.[a-zA-Z_][\w-_]*[^\.\s\{#:\,;]/g;
  var m;
  let classes = [];
  do {
    m = re.exec(cssdata);
    if (m) {
      for(let key in m) {
        if(
           (typeof m[key] == "string") && 
           (classes.indexOf(m[key]) == -1) &&
           (m[key].indexOf(".") == 0)
          )
          classes.push(m[key].replace(/\s/g, " "));
      }
    }
  } while (m);
  return classes;
}

function getHTMLUsedClasses() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var unique = function (list, x) {
    if (x && list.indexOf(x) === -1) {
        list.push(x);
    }
    return list;
  };
  var htmlclasses = [].reduce.call(elements, function (acc, e) {
    if (e.classList.length > 0){
      return  [].slice.call(e.classList).reduce(unique, acc);      
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
  }, []);
  return htmlclasses;
}


function getUndefinedClasses(cssclasses, htmlclasses) {
  var undefinedclasses = [];
  for (let key in htmlclasses) {
    if(cssclasses.indexOf("." + htmlclasses[key])  == -1 ) {
       undefinedclasses.push(htmlclasses[key]);
    }
  }
  return undefinedclasses;
}
//console.log(cssclasses)
var cssclasses = getAllClasses();

var htmlclasses = getHTMLUsedClasses();

var un = getUndefinedClasses(cssclasses, htmlclasses);

console.log(un )
//copy(un);
```